# iOS 10 iMessage Extension - Facebook Login not working

Tags: ios, facebook, ios10, imessage

I'm having trouble getting Facebook login to work within the message extension of my iOS app.  The Facebook login flow works great when running as an app, however when run as a message extension, the facebook login button simply sends me to a white screen, as if the WebView facebook is trying to load cannot be loaded.  I have added the correct .plist settings to both app/extension, and added both Bundle ID's to facebook app settings.  Are there any known issues with webviews / facebook auth/login not working in the iMessage extention.